# why are there different results in two scala running environments?

Tags: scala

I am reading Section 19.3 of the book "programming in scala 2nd", 
there is a snippet code  and some description around it in page 431:

**NOTE: FC17 x86_64 Scala-2.9.2**

```
 class Cell[T](init: T) {
 private[this] var current = init
 def get = current
 def set(x: T) { current = x }
 }
```

I modifyed this sample in two different enviroments:
in first one, I wrote the following code in a file Cell.scala

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
class Cell[+T](init: T) {
private[this] var current = init
    def get = current
    def set[U >: T](x: U) {
    current = x.asInstanceOf[T]
    println("current " + current)
}
}

object Cell {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val a1 = new Cell[B](new B)
 a1.set(new B)
 a1.set(new String("Dillon"))
 a1.get
}
}
```

and using the following command,  and got nothing error:

```
[abelard <at> localhost lower-bound]$ scalac Cell.scala
[abelard <at> localhost lower-bound]$ scala -cp . Cell
current B <at> 67591ba4
current Dillon
Dillon
[abelard <at> localhost lower-bound]$
```

in the second, I directly wrote the code under the REPL:

```
 scala> class Cell[+T](init: T) {
 | private[this] var current = init
 | def get = current
 | def set[U >: T](x: U) {current = x.asInstanceOf[T]
 | }}
defined class Cell

scala> val a1 = new Cell[B](new B)
a1: Cell[B] = Cell <at> 6717f3cb
scala> a1.set(new B)
scala> a1.set(new String("Dillon"))
scala> a1.get

java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to B
at .<init>(<console>:25)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

accordding to my uderstanding to covariant and lower-bound,
I think the second result is right, but I do not know why
the first one did not throw any error?

I know I must missing something, I want to get a compiling 
error as the second, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to get a compile error, because there's no problem at compile time. A `ClassCastException` is a runtime exception.

You should notice that the exception occurs after you evaluate `a1.get`, rather that when you perform the cast in `a1.set`. More precisely, it occurs when you try to assign that return value to a variable.

In your first scenario `a1.get` is not assigned to a value. In your second, you're assigning it to a value such as `res0` etc.

You can show that this is the problem by trying the following in the REPL:

```
scala> a1.get
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to B

scala> println(a1.get)
Dillon
```

Comment: thank you! I got it a little. I have another question:

Comment: thank you! I got it a little. and I have another question: why the type of res0 (as you assumed) is class B? and the type of current after "current = x.asInstanceOf[T]" in function set()  can be any type such as String in my sample?

Comment: @abelard20008 your get and current are both T, which is B for `Cell[B]`.  Your assignment says you know x is a T, too, whatever T happens to be.  Maybe you're wrong, of course. You may have stuffed a square peg into a round hole. The round hole is Object.

Comment: @som-snytt thanks! for verifying the type of current, I executed `println(current.getClass.getName)` after `current = x.asInstanceOf[T]` , and I got two diffferent results: (1) `current`'s type is B after a1.set(new B) (2) `current`'s type is java.lang.String after a1.set("Dillon") . so I think that `current`'s type can be changed? I must miss something!

Comment: @abelard20008 That's the difference between static type at compile-time and whatever type info is available at runtime. CCE means you lied when you said asInstanceOf, and the runtime type turned out to be wrong. So avoid asInstanceOf.

Comment: @som-snytt thanks, I can not fully understand your explanation: you said that the difference btw compile-time and runtime, but the two different results were produced all at runtime? another, what should I do if I want the same effect without asInstanceOf? thank you again for mentioning "avoid asInstanceOf"

Comment: @abelard20008 type safety means what you know statically about the type of a value. Read 19.5 for what you are attempting, and type-driven design. http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.5